# Variance at a datapoint?

Tags: regression, generalized-least-squares

I have been reading [Boyd and Vandenberghe's book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/) on optimisation, and wanted to understand more about weighted least squares in regression which they touch on a bit. This is used when the "constant variance" assumption is violated. However, I have not been able to understand properly what this assumption really means.

From what I've been finding ([this page](https://towardsdatascience.com/weighted-linear-regression-2ef23b12a6d7) is typical), it seems that every datapoint $(x_i, y_i)$ is associated to a variance $\sigma_i^2$, and we wish these all to be equal; the weights in weighted least squares are then $w_i=1/\sigma_i^2$.

However, I do not understand how the $\sigma_i^2$ are defined - variance is about a population rather than a single point. Is it simply that $\sigma_i^2$ is the variance of the population once we've removed the point $x_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your features are equal to a particular $x_i$, there is an entire distribution of possible $y_i$. Under the “constant variance” assumption, these distributions all have the same variance. Without that, the variance can fluctuate willy-nilly.

In the simulation below, I give an example (top) where the variance is the same no matter the features and an example (bottom) where the variance depends on the feature value. This idea can extend to situations with multiple features, but the graphing gets difficult.

```r
library(ggplot2)
N <- 1000
x <- runif(N, 0, 25)
y1 <- x + rnorm(N, 0, 1)
y2 <- x + rnorm(N, 0, 5*sin(x) + 5.5)
d1 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y1, group = "Constant Variance")
d2 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y2, group = "Non-constant Variance")
d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = group)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(row = vars(group)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: variance plots]

Notice how the plot on the right has these alternations of wide vs narrow spreads. This is because the variance depends on the value of the feature `x`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks! Just to make sure I am understanding it though: if all the assumptions required by least squares hold, I can use the residuals to approximate the variance $\sigma^2$, right? Because although I the $y_i's$ are taken from the different distributions you mention, the corresponding distributions of errors are each the same - they are all normal, with the same mean ($0$) and same variance. So I can conflate them, and use the residuals to model these identical distributions/this single distribution?

Comment: When the error term has a constant variance, then the conditional distributions have constant variance (even if other characteristics, often the mean, change), so you only have one value to estimate: the one variance common to all conditional distributions. @user1729